# R nested for loop with as.numeric runs but does not change to num

Tags: r, for-loop

Unfortunately, I was not able to find the solution to my question on here; thus, this new question.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Read in table from wikipedia with the `xml2` package and put it in a data frame. So far so good. Now, I would like to convert the chr items into num with as.numeric leaving out the the first column and the first row in every column.

```
if(!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(rvest, dplyr, xml2)
uebergewicht <- read_html("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cbergewicht")


uebergewicht <- uebergewicht %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    .[[2]] %>% # table number two at link
    html_table(fill=TRUE)

for (i in 2:5){
    for (j in 2:6){
        uebergewicht[j,i] <- as.numeric(uebergewicht[j,i])
    }
}
```

The code runs without any errors but leaves the chr items unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `read_html` is from `xml2` not `rvest`. I'll update your question.

Comment: @Hack-R While your comment is technically correct, the `rvest` library loads `xml2` as required package. Therefore, `read_html()` is available after `library(rvest)`. It is thus also not necessary to load the `xml2` library in addition to `rvest`.

Comment: @RHertel It didn't for me. That's why I said that. I had to install it separately.

Comment: @Hack-R Yes, the packages need to be installed separately. Or maybe `install.packages(rvest,dependencies=TRUE)` would do. But once both packages are installed, doesn' t `library(rvest)` automatically load `xml2`  on your system (in a "clean" R session or after `detach("package:rvest"); detach("package:xml2")`)?

Answer (score 2):

It is because each column of a `data.frame` is a vector, and all elements of a vector must be the same type. Since you are not changing all of the elements to type numeric, the class of the entire vector remains `chr`. See the example below.

```
vector<-c("a", as.numeric(1), as.numeric(3), as.numeric(5))
str(vector)
chr [1:4] "a" "1" "3" "5"

vector[2:4]<-as.numeric(vector[2:4])
str(vector)
chr [1:4] "a" "1" "3" "5"
```

If you tried something like `vector<-as.numeric(vector)` you would get:

```
Warning message:
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

And you will lose some of the information stored in your vector.

```
str(vector)
num [1:4] NA 1 3 5
```

Comment: Thanks @BryanGoggin! That was the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments!

I was able to solve it via subsetting:

```
uebergewicht <- read_html("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cbergewicht")


uebergewicht <- uebergewicht %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    .[[2]] %>%
    html_table(fill=TRUE)

ueber_sub <- uebergewicht[2:6, 2:5]

names(ueber_sub) <- c("jungen.ueber", "jungen.adi", "mädchen.ueber", "mädchen.adi")

for (i in 1:4){
ueber_sub[,i] <- as.numeric(ueber_sub[,i])
}

> str(ueber_sub)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ jungen.ueber  : num  6.4 8.9 11.3 9 8.8
 $ jungen.adi    : num  2.5 7 7 8.2 6.3
 $ maädchen.ueber: num  6 9 11.6 8.1 8.5
 $ maädchen.adi  : num  3.3 5.7 7.3 8.9 6.4
```

Through subsetting, we get rid of the first line of each column, which would cause the column-vector to stay chr. I simply recoded the column names to reflect the information from row 1. That way, everything that goes into the for-loop is converted to num.

I didn't have any issues with the packages by the way.